# how to implement command ls -l using execvp?

Tags: system-calls, execvp

I try to implement command `ls -l` using `execvp`.
I have code

```
execvp("ls",&argv[0]);
```

work good, but i use

```
execvp("ls -l",&argv[0]);
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `execvp()` needs to be the binary name you want to run. You can't just add additional arguments in there. The argument list is coming from the `&argv[0]`. You'll need to create a new array to insert your argument. Something like this:

```
char** new_args = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char*));
new_args[0] = argv[0];
new_args[1] = "-l";
memcpy(&new_args[2], &argv[1], (argc - 1) * sizeof(char*));
execvp("ls", new_args);
```